# How would you go about writing a custom script that grabs the Adobe or Google Analytics image request?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, adobe-analytics

If I wanted to build a scraper that pings each URL on a site and stores the adobe (or Google) image request, how would I go about this? I.e. I just want something that grabs all the parameters in the URL posted to Adobe in a csv or something similar. I'm familiar with how to build simple web scrapers, but how do I grab the URL I see in for example Fiddler that contains all the variables being sent to the Analytics solution?

If I could do this I could run a script that lists all URLs with the corresponding tracking events that are being fired and it would make QAing much more manageable.

Comment: I think this is to broad for an SO answer, but I suggest you look into phantomjs (headless browser that can download a page while tracing all http call the page makes).

Comment: Hi, it seems an awesome idea, I need something like that as well. It seems to be easier in a server side, some proxy sniffing the network and filtering the adobe requests. I'm working on that, wishes that you find some help first!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to query the DOM for the image object created by the tag request.  I am more familiar with the IBM Digital Analytics (Coremetrics) platform and you can find the tag requests using accessing the following array `document.cmTagCtl.cTI` in the Web Console on a Coremetrics tagged page. I used this method when building a Selenium WebDriver test case and wanted to test for the analytics tags.

I don't have the equivalent for Adobe or GA at the moment since it depends in the library implementation am trying the do the same as you for GA.

Cheers,
Jamie